# Horizontal scaling with SignalR app

Tags: c#, asp-net-core-mvc

у меня есть приложение asp net core signal в docker swarm с redis

Мне время от времени нужно проверять, подключен ли указанный юзер в signalR

С помощью только 1 реплики я могу создать такой список

```
public static readonly List<string> Connected = new();
```

Туда и буду добавлять или удалять юзера через **OnConnectedAsync** и **OnDisconnectedAsync**

Но когда я делаю масштабирование, этот метод больше не работает

Вопрос: как мне проделать такой трюк?

я читал
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

и мне нравится реализация через базу данных, но я могу понять, как мне убирать соединение при краше сервеа

Например
2 сервера, 1 redis, 1 бд с подключением-
По идее все ок, но если 1 сервер упал, он не не триггернет
**OnDisconnectedAsync**
и поэтому в бд будут старые неактуальные соединения

Comment: не знаю за конкретно ваш случай, но обычно клиент и сервер постоянно обмениваются какимито пакетами данных, которые просто указывают, что пользователь подключён к серверу а сервер к пользователю, делают максимальную задержку и проверяют, если задержка ответа больше максимальной - сервер или клиент отключились

Comment: В моем случае два хаба, 1 для консольного приложения, 2й для веба. Мне нужно как то детектить, что консолька открыта и передавать на веб.